# WordPress doesn't send a password (but only a username) after new user registration

Tags: user-registration, password

After a new user registration is made, WordPress doesn't send a password, but it sends only a username as you can see the email below. How can I have the password?

```
Hi [username],


Thanks for registering on [www.example.com] Your account is now active.


To login please fill out your credentials on:
https://www.example.com/login/


Your Username: [username]



Have a nice day!
```

Comment: For that case, he said "WP sends out an email with the login / password" That means he received the password, right? But for my case, I don't receive a password, just only the username. Does the default email  sends out both username and password or just only username?

Comment: If it sends out  both username and password, then this is not duplicated. Because I don't receive a password. And I do not talk about how to change the default email, I talk about that I don't receive a password.

Comment: WordPress doesn't send passwords via email because it's *very* bad security to do so. You can read more about it [here](https://blog.nexcess.net/2016/01/20/wordpress-no-longer-emails-passwords-which-is-great-for-site-security/). @JackJohansson The `$plaintext_pass` parameter that answer depends on has been deprecated since 4.3.1.